# Tablesorter: sorting the Czech alphabet

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter, non-english

Im using tablesorter characterEquivalents extend as it is described in http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-locale-sort.html.

I prepared similar extend for czech characters, but the sorting do not work for some characters - f. e. **\u017d**

```
$.extend( $.tablesorter.characterEquivalents, {
"a" : "\u00e1", // á
"A" : "\u00c1", // Á
"c" : "\u010d", // č
"C" : "\u010c", // Č
"d" : "\u010f", // ď
"D" : "\u010e", // Ď
"e" : "\u00e9\u011b", // éě
"E" : "\u00c9\u011a", // ÉĚ
"i" : "\u00ed", // í
"I" : "\u00cd", // Í
"n" : "\u0148", // ň
"N" : "\u0147", // Ň
"o" : "\u00f3", // ó
"O" : "\u00d3", // Ó    
"r" : "\u0159", // ř
"R" : "\u0158", // Ř
"s" : "\u0161", // š
"Š" : "\u0160", // Š
"t" : "\u0165", // ť
"T" : "\u0164", // Ť        
"u" : "\u00fa\u016f", // úů
"U" : "\u00da\u016e", // ÚŮ
"y" : "\u00fd", // ý
"Y" : "\u00dd", // Ý    
"z" : "\u017e", // ž
"Z" : "\u017d" // Ž
});
```

In example here http://jsfiddle.net/Gk43v/18/ there is issue that **Ž** is before **Z** which is wrong.

But on my pages is Ž is in middle of the table which is completely wrong.

Comment: My pages are here http://www.sl-skole.cz/eshop.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working. The "z" has been replaced in the internal cache.

Although you might need to include a `true` flag to perform a deep extend:

```
$.extend( true, $.tablesorter.characterEquivalents, { ... });
```

Check out this demo (sort to see the column values in the firebug window): http://jsfiddle.net/Gk43v/19/

---

Update: Ok, the issue appears to be the actual sort order. The problem is that the default sort is done using the ASCII value of the characters, so that Š and Ž sort after A-Z without any character-equivalent replacement. The function replaces "S" for "Š" and "Z" for "Ž", making them equivalent and indistinguishable from their unaccented letters.

If you truly want the sort to maintain character order, you'll need to use a different text sorter like [sugarjs](http://sugarjs.com/arrays#sorting) which allows you to set a sort order:

```
Array.AlphanumericSortOrder = 'AaÁáBbCcDdÐðEeÉéĘęFfGgHhIiÍíJjKkLlMmNnOoÓóPpQqRrSsTtUuÚúVvWwXxYyÝýZzÞþÆæÖö';
```

You can then use the [`textSorter` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#textsorter) to use the sugar array sort for that column - [here is a demo showing an Icelandic sort](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-option-custom-sort.html)

```
$("table").tablesorter({
  theme : 'blue',
  ignoreCase : false,
  textSorter : {
    // alphanumeric sort from sugar (http://sugarjs.com/arrays#sorting)
    // for the first column (zero-based index)
    0 : Array.AlphanumericSort
  }
});
```

---

Update #2: Because the Czech alphabet is a bit more complex, you'll need to replace the "CH" with a placholder because Sugar only allows single characters in the sort order definition.

So in this example, I replaced "CH" with "Æ" ([updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Gk43v/23/))

```
$(function () {
    Array.AlphanumericSortOrder = 'AaÁáÄäBbCcČčDdĎďEeÉéĚěFfGgHhÆæIiÍíJjKkLlMmNnŇňOoÓóÖöPpQqRrŘřSsŠšTtŤťUuÚúŮůÜüVvWwXxYyÝýZzŽž';
    Array.AlphanumericSortIgnoreCase = true;
    // see https://github.com/andrewplummer/Sugar/issues/382#issuecomment-41526957
    Array.AlphanumericSortEquivalents = {};

    // replace "Ch" and "ch" with a placeholder... it can be anything
    // in this example, I'm replacing ch with "æ" and Ch or CH with "Æ"
    // these characters have been added to the Array.AlphanumericSortOrder
    // between "h" and "I" - according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czech_orthography
    var replaceCH = function( node ) {
        return $(node).text()
            .replace(/(Ch|CH)/g, '\u00c6')
            .replace(/ch/g, '\u00e6');
    };

    $("table").tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        // table = table object; get config options from table.config
        // column is the column index (zero-based)
        ignoreCase: false,
        textExtraction : {
            1: replaceCH,
            3: replaceCH
        },
        textSorter: {
            1 : Array.AlphanumericSort, // alphanumeric sort from sugar (http://sugarjs.com/arrays#sorting)
            3 : Array.AlphanumericSort
        }
    });
});
```

I did try to use the `characterEquivalents` function to replace the string, but it also currently only supports single character replacements (I'll fix this in a future version), so for now I am using a custom `textExtraction` function.

The second issue you reported can be solved by triggering an ["update" method](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#update) on the table after the ajax call completes and the table is rendered.

```
$('table').trigger('update');
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Sorry but I still didn`t get how to achieve the correct letters order. In the example its **Á,Č,É,Š,S,Ů,Ž,Z** and  the correct order is **Á,Č,É,S,Š,Ů,Z,Ž**.

Comment: Thank you for your outstanding help, now it looks much better in demo http://jsfiddle.net/Gk43v/21/. Unfortunately I'm still facing two remaining issues. First prbolem is letter **CH** which is special in czech (you can find it here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czech_orthography) and Im not sure how to implement it to the sort order. Seccond bigger issue is that on my pages where I import data via AJAX from XML the AlphanumericSortOrder don´t work. (see here http://www.sl-skole.cz/eshop_test.php)

Comment: I've updated my answer again ;) Also, the page you shared isn't loading Sugar - there is an error in the console.

Comment: Mottie, thank you again so much, letter **CH** is sorted absolutely correct in demo http://jsfiddle.net/Gk43v/24/. You are right I forgot to upload sugar, but unfortunately the sorting still not work on my pages. I tried everything, here is exactly the same configuration as on jsfiddle, but the sorting is not working (see http://www.sl-skole.cz/czechsort.html - I use same versions of talbesorter, jquery and sugar).

Comment: The `Array.AlphanumericSortOrder` definition in `engine.js` is all messed up... make sure to save the file in a UTF-8 format. If you don't know how to do that, then use this instead: `Array.AlphanumericSortOrder="Aa\u00c1\u00e1\u00c4\u00e4BbCc\u010c\u010dDd\u010e\u010fEe\u00c9\u00e9\u011a\u011bFfGgHh\u00c6\u00e6Ii\u00cd\u00edJjKkLlMmNn\u0147\u0148Oo\u00d3\u00f3\u00d6\u00f6PpQqRr\u0158\u0159Ss\u0160\u0161Tt\u0164\u0165Uu\u00da\u00fa\u016e\u016f\u00dc\u00fcVvWwXxYy\u00dd\u00fdZz\u017d\u017e";` - I copy/pasted that line into http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Comment: I saved the file in another editor in UTF-8 and the issue has been completely solved. I simply don't know how to thank you for your amazing help, I would never except approach like this! I think you could add czech the page https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/wiki/Language. Have a nice day man.

Comment: Added to the language page: https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/wiki/Language#czech Thanks!